# Send data from Widget Configuration to viewsFactory Android

Tags: android, listview, widget

Upon adding a new widget a configuration activity popups which inflates a listview of names from database and when i select the name from the config activity it pass the position to Appwidget provider

```
 static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        final CharSequence recipeId = IngredientConfiguration.loadTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);

        String recipeIdInt = recipeId.toString();

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.ingredient_widget);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ListViewService.class);
        remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_listview, intent);

        remoteViews.setEmptyView(R.id.widget_listview, R.id.empty_view);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
    }
```

i created the remoteviewservice factory which inflates listview from database with cursor with position 0.

i want to get the info from config activity and use that value in remoteviewfactory and inflate the listview with unique value

Answer (score 2):

Just add your parameters to adapter intent. Check out a simple example.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExampleRemoteService.class);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
intent.putExtra("group", group);
intent.putExtra("week", week);
intent.putExtra("day", day);
remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.example, intent);
```

In ExampleRemoteService in method onGetViewFactory you can get this intent and transfer to ExampleViewsFactory.

```
@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
    return (new ExampleViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(),
            intent));
}
```

In ExampleViewsFactory take all intent's data and in OnCreate just load your list depends on this parameters.

```
private String group;
private int widgetId;
private int week;
private int day;
private List<ExampleModel> data = new ArrayList<>();

public ExampleViewsFactory(Context context, Intent adapter) {
    this.group = adapter.getStringExtra("group");
    this.day = adapter.getIntExtra("day", 0);
    this.week = adapter.getIntExtra("week", 0);
    this.widgetId = adapter.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
            AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    this.data = exampleRepository.getDataByWeekAndDay(group, week, day);
}
```

Now you need only to make a remoteviews for all items.

Comment: You can't get custom extras that you passed via intent in your factory class, it always returns null

Comment: are you that you pass correct intent? if yes, this kind of behavior is seems impossible, so i can check this behavior if you push a sample on Github

Comment: `onGetViewFactory` didn't get called at the second time.